# How to get last part of nvarchar with variable size in T-SQL?

Tags: t-sql, nvarchar

Imagine that I have the following value in my `nvarchar` variable:

```
DECLARE @txt nvarchar(255)
SET @txt = '32|foo|foo2|123'
```

Is there a way to easily get the last part just after the last `|` that is `123` in this case ?

I could write a `split` function but I'm not interested in the first parts of this string. Is there another way to get that last part of the string without getting the first parts ?

Note that all parts of my string have variable sizes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`LEFT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx), [`REVERSE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx) and [`CHARINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx) for this.
The query below reverses the string, finds the first occurance of `|`, strips out other characters and then straightens the string back.

```
DECLARE @txt nvarchar(255)
SET @txt = '32|foo|foo2|123'

SELECT REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(@txt),CHARINDEX('|',REVERSE(@txt))-1))
```

**Output**

```
123
```

**Edit**

If your string only has 4 parts or less and `.` isn't a valid character, you can also use [`PARSENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) for this.

```
DECLARE @txt nvarchar(255)
SET @txt = '32|foo|foo2|123'
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(@txt,'|','.'),1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse your string to get the desired result:

```
DECLARE @txt nvarchar(255) = '32|foo|foo2|123'
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(@txt), 1, CHARINDEX('|', REVERSE(@txt)) -1))
```

Comment: Works perfectly ! I will accept ughai's answer because I prefer the use of `LEFT` but thank you anyway. +1 :)

Comment: @Aleph0, you are welcome. Fill free to choose any answer that best fits your needs.